# Storing list of lists efficiently (sieving)

Tags: c, math, optimization, data-structures, prime-factoring

### Question

I'm looking for a data structure for a project in C to store a list of lists. I need to be able to access the n-th list given just n (the terms will be accessed out of order). The individual lists will contain between 1 and M integers (say M = 25 for concreteness); the outer list contains N of these. The individual lists are closer to 1 than M on average: in my example, only 20% have between 5 and 25 elements.

The obvious implementation is an array of length N*M. But this is space-inefficient: for performance reasons, it's important that the structure not take up too much memory. What is a good way to do this?

### Context

I'm writing a factorization sieve. The outer array represents numbers from S*b + 1 to S*(b+1), and each of the arrays store the prime factors of one number in that range. The smaller the structure gets the larger S can be chosen, reducing the number of (expensive) divisions.

This also gives another avenue for optimization: store only primes greater than or equal to L. The benefit is that instead of needing floor(log_2(x = largest number in range)) elements in each list, you need only floor(log_L(x)). (The example above corresponds to x = 10^12, L = 3.) The downside is that to reconstruct the factorization one needs to do trial division for primes below L.

In my application each factorization is reconstructed once, so increasing L to the next prime costs (somewhat more than) 10^12 additional divisions in my example; as an order of magnitude, this is 24-87 ops each or 2-8 hours in total on a 3 GHz K10. The more efficient the memory structure, the fewer 2 to 8 hour chinks I'll need to spend. (On the flip side, memory structures that take too much CPU work aren't worth it unless they provide a better tradeoff.)

Comment: why not cheat a little and hold a small list of 100 first known primes? with how large N must you deal with?

Comment: Why not store an array of N pointers to lists?

Comment: Is M or N expected to be larger? Can you give a rough range of these values?

Comment: also [link](http://m-hewedy.blogspot.co.il/2010/09/java-like-arraylist-in-c.html) is a reference for a well-designed implementation of array list for C which might save you the trouble of using a sieve.at all

Comment: @GiladMitrani: N will typically be around 10^5 to 10^8, depending on speed/size of cache and main memory. If the range up to 10^12 is to be checked this will take 10^4 to 10^7 invocations of the program.

Comment: @matanso: Because the individual lists will change (see the "context" section) it seems unlikely that this would be efficient for my application.

Comment: @DanielJour: N will be much, much larger. It could be as small as 10^5 if I keep everything in cache, or 10^8 if I use RAM. M on the other hand will certainly be less than 50.

Comment: @GiladMitrani: Since the individual lists will be dynamically generated (see "Context" section), that would cause a large number of calls to `arrayCopy` and that's exactly the kind of thrashing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: For what purpose are you writing this (ie: work/educational/homework)? How how are L and S? Is there a benefit to simply downloading a list of say the few million or billion primes from the web?

Comment: @Nuclearman: The purpose is adding a feature to [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/). I'll probably use L = 3 but perhaps I might use L as high as, say, 97. The size of S depends on the cache behavior; probably around 10^5, but could be up to a thousand times larger. But before I can optimize these values I need to find a good memory structure. The naive two-dimensional array where the second dimension is the full size would suggest using a fairly large L but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @Nuclearman: Oh, and on the last part: no, there would be no advantage to downloading such a list. Generating primes by a sieve is easy -- using the trivial bit array takes only 1% of the size of 25 quadwords as in my problem, and if you work a bit harder you can pack a block of size 30 into a byte (since primes greater than 5 are in one of 8 residue classes mod 30). This is fast enough that downloading is much slower. My application is _factoring_, not prime generation, and since I want to go up to 10^12 or 10^13 I'd need a petabyte of storage (well, or somewhat less if I get a good answer).

Comment: @Charles Will the lists be generated sequentially, in random order, or in some non-random but non-sequential manner?

Comment: @mhum: If I understand correctly, the answer is "in some non-random but non-sequential order". If I was working on the range 1..100 I would start with 100 empty lists, then I would add 3 to entries 3, 6, 9, ..., 99, then I would add a second 3 to entries 9, 18, 27, ..., 99, then I would add a third 3 to 27, 54, and 81, then I would add a fourth 3 to 81, then I would add a 5 to 5, 10, 15, ..., 100, then a second 5 to 25, 50, 75, and 100, then I would add 7s... so it's skipping all over. It's pretty cache-unfriendly, though I understand there are ways to improve it in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

One data structure which comes to mind is a two-dimensional array where the 'inner' array is a fair bit smaller than floor(log_L(x)). If there are prime factors left over then store a pointer in the last element, which goes to a secondary overflow array. You can also reduce the storage needed by leaving off the last prime factor, which can be determined by dividing out the others.

I don't know if this is much better than the naive approach. The upside is that memory usage is much smaller -- maybe 5 elements instead of 25, letting you pack in 4 to 5 times as many numbers in the same space. The downside is that it's more work to reconstruct the numbers and memory locality might be slightly worse.

But there's another trick which may help. As long as L > 2, all of the numbers in the list will be odd, so the last bit is unused. You could use this to store the exponent in the number itself: store p * 2^(e-1) instead of p. So "3" represents 3, "6" represents 3^2, "12" represents 3^3, and so on. If you use 64-bit numbers you can represent 3^63 as 3*2^62 which is less than 2^64. (Larger bases are easier: 5^62 is 18 trillion times larger than 3^63 but can be represented in this format with 64 bits.) 32 bits limits you to 3^31, but you already can't represent the prime 2^32 + 15, which makes the limit somewhat more than 2^64.

Actually, I think this is good enough that the secondary array can be skipped entirely. Here's a list showing how many factors you need to store

Using 1 `uint32_t` lets you store factored numbers less than 3*5*7 = 105 (7 bits).

Using 2 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*5*7*11 = 1155 (11 bits).

Using 3 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*5*7*11*13 = 15015 (14 bits).

Using 4 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*17 = 255255 (18 bits).

Using 5 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*19 (23 bits).

Using 6 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*23 (27 bits).

Using 7 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*29 (32 bits).

Using 8 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*31 (37 bits).

Using 9 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*37 (42 bits).

Using 10 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*41 (48 bits).

Using 11 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*43 (53 bits).

Using 12 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*47 (59 bits).

Using 13 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than 3*...*53 (64 bits).

Using 14 `uint32_t`s lets you store factored numbers less than (2^32 + 15)^2 (64 bits).

To go beyond this you'd probably want to use the alternate data structure I mentioned (where the secondary array uses `uint64_t`) so you don't need to convert the main array to `uint64_t`. But this is only of concern for segmented sieving; it's infeasible to sieve all the numbers up to 2^64 -- it would take hundreds of years.

Comment: +1 I was thinking about approximately the same data structure. It would be really interesting to see whether locality would ruin it, though.